# Как изменить стартовую Activity в Android?

Tags: android, activity

Я создал основную, mainactivity, на которой создал поля для входа и регистрации. Допустим, пользователь зарегистрировался и вошёл, его перекидывает в main2activity. Но после выхода из приложения и обратного захода пользователь пять попадает на mainactivity. Мне же нужно как-то проверять этот "заход", и в случае корректной авторизации сделать так, чтобы пользователь попадал сразу в main2activity.

Answer (score 1):

Вам надо сохранить состояние пользователя. К примеру, пользователь прошел авторизацию, Вы сохраняете нужные данные в какой-то `sharedPreferences`. И считывать этот `sharedPreferences` при запуске. Т.е., если пользователь открыл приложение и `isOnline = false`, значит открыть `МейнАктивити`, а если пользователь открыл приложение, но `isOnline = true`, то перекинуть его в `НекстАктивити`. Кстати, если использователь авторизацию через `Гугл`, то он сам сохраняет состояние, т.е., даже если переустановить приложение и открыть его - пользователь будет онлайн.

upd.

1. Создаете переменные.

`var sharedPreferencesStatusNews = "news"` `//Ключ`

`lateinit var sharedPreferencesNews: SharedPreferences` `//Сам обьект`

И добавляете эту строку в `onCreate`.

`sharedPreferencesNews = activity!!.getSharedPreferences(sharedPreferencesStatusNews, Context.MODE_PRIVATE)`

2. Переопределяете метод `onPause()`, к примеру, и туда вписываете этот код.
   Тут все просто. Создаете едитор, добавляете данные под нужный ключ и сохраняете при выходе, т.к. этот метод в методе `onPause()`.

`val editor1 = sharedPreferencesNews.edit()
        editor1.putBoolean(sharedPreferencesStatusNews, "значение")
        editor1.apply()`

3. Переопределяете метод `onResume()` и вписываете этот код туда. Тут Вы спрашиваете, содержит ли обьект значение по такому-то айди. Если да, то создаете переменную и получаете значение по этому ключу. И затем можете создать `if-else`для действий.

`if (sharedPreferencesNews.contains(sharedPreferencesStatusNews)) {`

```
var result = sharedPreferencesNews.getBoolean(sharedPreferencesStatusNews, false)

if (result == true) {

} else {

}
```

`}`

Comment: Спасибо, попытаюсь сделать

Comment: Если я скину вам свой код, сможете вы конкретно показать?

Comment: Добавиш в ответ выше пример.

Comment: Добавил*.  Попробуйте.

Comment: Спасибо большое